# match column from a dataset to another under condition in R

Tags: r

I have 2 data set that look like this

```
#set1:
DOB.data <- structure(list(name = c("A", "B", "C"), DOB = c("13/12/2000", 
"13/12/2001", "13/12/2002")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

#set2:
DOB.data2<-structure(list(name = c("A", "B", "C", "DD"), x = c("1", "2", "3","4")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

How do I match DOB column into the other data set based on their name?

Say DOB.data will match the name and left the other that doesn't have matching data in NA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean

```
DOB.data %>%
  full_join(DOB.data2, by = "name")

  name        DOB x
1    A 13/12/2000 1
2    B 13/12/2001 2
3    C 13/12/2002 3
4   DD       <NA> 4
```

Answer (score 0):

set2 should have `row.names = c(NA, -4L))`, not `row.names = c(NA, -3L))`

not sure what do you want to achieve, but as @Park said, you should take a look at the dplyr `*_join` functions:

```
library(dplyr)

new1 <- inner_join(DOB.data, DOB.data2, by = "name") # in new dataset, leave only names which exist in both DOB.data and DOB.data2 and include unique columns from both datasets

new2 <- left_join(DOB.data, DOB.data2, by = "name") # in new dataset, leave only names which exist in DOB.data and DOB.data2 and include unique columns from both datasets, check out the right_join also

new3 <- full_join(DOB.data, DOB.data2, by = "name") # in new dataset include all names from both DOB.data and DOB.data2 and include unique columns from both datasets
```